# Show paragraphs one at a time

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi I would like to have paragraphs become visible one at a time as you click on a button.
Can i have it so that you only need one button to reveal the paragraphs one at a time.I have managed to get it going, but the solution i have seems very long winded as i need a button for each paragraph which seems a tedious task.

This is my code:

```js
$("#butt1").click(function() {
  $("#para1").show();
});
$("#butt2").click(function() {
  $("#para2").show();
});
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="butt1">1</button>
<button id="butt2">2</button>
<p id="para1">1. Paragraph One</p>
<p id="para2">2. Paragraph Two</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using identifiers for this.
As follows, "`.show`" must define a target for the first match that does not contain a specific class and automate it.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $(this).text('Show Next Paragraph');
  $("p:not(.show)").first().addClass('show');
});
```

```css
p:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Show Paragraph</button>
<p id="para1">1. Paragraph One</p>
<p id="para2">2. Paragraph Two</p>
<p>3. Paragraph Three</p>
<p>4. Paragraph Four</p>
<p>5. Paragraph Five</p>
```

Comment: Hi BOZ, you are a star, excellent solution and exactly what i wanted, wish i could give your more votes

Comment: @Ray I'm glad this works for you. That's enough for me :)